# How to Convert Panel grid to pageblock table in visualforce?with similar UI

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable, panelgrid

I have a Panel Grid with static data of 10 fields of a record. look below code`

```
<apex:panelGrid columns="4" styleClass="CostCenterGrid" id="eventCRSection" rendered="{!eventCREditSection}">
                          <apex:outputText value="Cost center Number" style="font-weight: bold"/>

    <apex:outputText value="Cost Center" style="font-weight: bold"/>

    <apex:outputText value="Cost Center Budget Percentage" style="font-weight: bold"/>

    <apex:outputText value="" style="font-weight: bold"/>

    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter1" value="{!$ObjectType.ahm__Interaction__c.fields.ahm__Cost_Center_1__c.Label}" styleClass="labelCol" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_1__c}" id="interactionCostCenter1" styleClass="inputCostCenter1 inputCostCenter" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_1_Percentage__c}" id="interactionCostCenter1Percentage" styleClass="inputCostCenter1Percentage inputCostCenterPercentage" />
    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter1Percentage" value="%" />

    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter2" value="{!$ObjectType.ahm__Interaction__c.fields.ahm__Cost_Center_2__c.Label}" styleClass="labelCol" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_2__c}" id="interactionCostCenter2" styleClass="inputCostCenter2 inputCostCenter" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_2_Percentage__c}" id="interactionCostCenter2Percentage" styleClass="inputCostCenter2Percentage inputCostCenterPercentage" />
    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter2Percentage" value="%" />

    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter3" value="{!$ObjectType.ahm__Interaction__c.fields.ahm__Cost_Center_3__c.Label}" styleClass="labelCol" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_3__c}" id="interactionCostCenter3" styleClass="inputCostCenter3 inputCostCenter" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_3_Percentage__c}" id="interactionCostCenter3Percentage" styleClass="inputCostCenter3Percentage inputCostCenterPercentage" />
    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter3Percentage" value="%" />

    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter4" value="{!$ObjectType.ahm__Interaction__c.fields.ahm__Cost_Center_4__c.Label}" styleClass="labelCol" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_4__c}" id="interactionCostCenter4" styleClass="inputCostCenter4 inputCostCenter" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_4_Percentage__c}" id="interactionCostCenter4Percentage" styleClass="inputCostCenter4Percentage inputCostCenterPercentage" />
    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter4Percentage" value="%" />

    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter1" value="{!$ObjectType.ahm__Interaction__c.fields.ahm__Cost_Center_5__c.Label}" styleClass="labelCol" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_5__c}" id="interactionCostCenter5" styleClass="inputCostCenter5 inputCostCenter" />

    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_5_Percentage__c}" id="interactionCostCenter5Percentage" styleClass="inputCostCenter5Percentage inputCostCenterPercentage"  />
    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter5Percentage" value="%" />

    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter6" value="{!$ObjectType.ahm__Interaction__c.fields.ahm__Cost_Center_6__c.Label}" styleClass="labelCol" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_6__c}" id="interactionCostCenter6" styleClass="inputCostCenter6 inputCostCenter" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_6_Percentage__c}" id="interactionCostCenter6Percentage" styleClass="inputCostCenter6Percentage inputCostCenterPercentage" />
    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter6Percentage" value="%" />

    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter7" value="{!$ObjectType.ahm__Interaction__c.fields.ahm__Cost_Center_7__c.Label}" styleClass="labelCol" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_7__c}" id="interactionCostCenter7" styleClass="inputCostCenter7 inputCostCenter" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_7_Percentage__c}" id="interactionCostCenter7Percentage" styleClass="inputCostCenter7Percentage inputCostCenterPercentage" />
    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter7Percentage" value="%" />

    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter8" value="{!$ObjectType.ahm__Interaction__c.fields.ahm__Cost_Center_8__c.Label}" styleClass="labelCol" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_8__c}" id="interactionCostCenter8" styleClass="inputCostCenter8 inputCostCenter" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_8_Percentage__c}" id="interactionCostCenter8Percentage" styleClass="inputCostCenter8Percentage inputCostCenterPercentage" />
    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter8Percentage" value="%" />

    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter9" value="{!$ObjectType.ahm__Interaction__c.fields.ahm__Cost_Center_9__c.Label}" styleClass="labelCol" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_9__c}" id="interactionCostCenter9" styleClass="inputCostCenter9 inputCostCenter" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_9_Percentage__c}" id="interactionCostCenter9Percentage" styleClass="inputCostCenter9Percentage inputCostCenterPercentage" />
    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter9Percentage" value="%" />

    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter10" value="{!$ObjectType.ahm__Interaction__c.fields.ahm__Cost_Center_10__c.Label}" styleClass="labelCol" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_10__c}" id="interactionCostCenter10" styleClass="inputCostCenter10 inputCostCenter" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!intcostcenter.ahm__Cost_Center_10_Percentage__c}" id="interactionCostCenter10Percentage" styleClass="inputCostCenter10Percentage inputCostCenterPercentage" />
    <apex:outputLabel for="interactionCostCenter10Percentage" value="%" />

</apex:panelGrid>
```

Please refer the screenshot how I am showing Presently.But I need the same data to be shown in Page block Table with fixed no of rows. Can someone help me on this?[image: Panel Grid Output]

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to add a controller also. Create a class with with 3 variables as you have 3 columns. I am showing you a piece of code just for demo.

```
   VF page      
     <apex:pageBlock title="Any title">
        // here Temp is list of object which you have set in your controller.
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Temp}" var="contact">
          <apex:column value="{!temp.column1}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!temp.column2}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!temp.column3}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:pageBlock>
```

Below is the controller

```
 public class yourControllerName{
 public list<yourControllerName> temp {get;set;}
 public String column1;
 public String column2;
 public String column3;

  public yourControllerName(){
  yourControllerName a = new yourControllerName ();
  temp  = new List<yourControllerName>();
  a.column1='any value';
  a.column2='any value';
  a.column3='any value';
  temp.add(a);
  }
}
```

Comment: The above implementation is for page block table, here I need static table not just pageblock table. With rows from different fields of same record. For example from my above sample code, all the cost centers belong to one record and I want the table rows with static values.